# Can a nominalized clause contain a topic and a focus?

Tags: syntax, embedding, topic-comment, nominalization

one:    I’ve heard about foci in sentences—the new information typically shown in the predicate. For instance, in the sentence “Reece turned out to be the mysterious super-hero,”
...

“Reece” is the topic/the old information, and “turned out to be the mysterious super-hero.” is the focus/new information.

We can divide the following sentences in the same way.

•   The mountain goat (topic) died in a rare fall (focus).
•   The hornets (topic) built a nest in our attic (focus).
•   Elephants (topic) never forget (focus).
•   I (topic) want to marry Sally (focus).

In some English constructions, the focus can occur before the topic.

•   It was Reece (focus) who turned out to be the mysterious super-hero (topic).
•   It was the monkeys (focus) that stole our apples (topic).
•   It was baby iguanas (focus) that the birds were after (topic).
•   It was the lion (focus) that scared me (topic)

Question:   Do nominalized clauses have topics and foci?   It seems to me that the entire nominalized clause can be either a topic or a focus or part of a focus.

•   John’s slurping the soup (topic) bothered Jean (focus).
•   The zookeeper (topic) knew about the elephant’s eating marshmallows (focus).

But is there any linguistic context in which a nominalized clause **contains** both a topic and a focus?

Comment: If the categories of "topic" and "focus" are relevant for "it was Reece who turned out to be the hero", would they not also be relevant for "the fact that it was Reece who turned out to be the hero"?

Comment: The purpose of Cleft constructions like _What I liked was the frosting_ or _It was the frosting that I liked_ is to move topic or focus into new positions where they're more easily parsed and identified. Occasionally the function to swap the roles.

Comment: @Draconis Intuitively I agree, but things get tricky when you try to apply definitions: if you're working in a Lambrechtian framework where focus is defined as the difference between the assertion and the presupposition, then in e.g. *The fact that it was Reece who turned out to be the hero surprised everyone*, the entire nominalized clause would seem to be presupposed and therefore non-focal.  Which clearly misses something important -- I don't know if there are any information-structure theories out there that grapple with the inner structure of subordinate clauses.